# Balanced brackets algorithm with different symbols

Tags: java, python, algorithm

We all know the regular balanced brackets algorithm and it's appeared here in many variations, but I have another twist.

I know how to answer it with ,or without a stack, and I have read all of the threads relating this problem here ,and on google but I haven't found any answer that matches my problem.

Let's invent a different kind of math, instead of '()','{}','[]' we use '**','$$','##'. Now show an algorithm to check wheatear the parenthesis are balanced.

for example: *##$$##*** is legit, equivalent to ([[{}]])() or even ([]{}).
It's probably not the best different symbols mean different things if it was real math, but it's not math were dealing with...

I tried using the solution for the 'regular' symbols and adjust it to work with this new symbols but for now I've failed. The problem is of course we can't tell between opening and closing symbol. Can anyone suggest a solution?

This was given to me as one of the questions in a job interview, while before that I solved it with the regular symbols. Not that it matters but I was asked to answer using Java.

Comment: This seems like a simpler case of the 'regular' symbols problem - when the current symbol is the same as the head of the stack, you pop it from the stack (i.e. treat the current symbol as a closing bracket), otherwise you add the symbol to the stack (i.e. treat it as an opening bracket). The stack must be empty when the input is done.

Comment: `(()) --> ****` and `()() --> ****` would have an equal representation. So you cant convert it into an old representation but you can check if the input has at least one valid representation.

Comment: I don't have the right answer but I'm starting to think I was tricked to think it would be more complicated

Answer (score 2):

You can just be greedy and pop any time that you have a match on the top of the stack.

```
def is_valid(string):
    stack = []
    for char in string:
        if stack and char == stack[-1]:
            stack.pop()
        else:
            stack.push(char)
    return not stack
```